# How did Audrey Eastman know Jessica Jones was "gifted"?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, jessica-jones-2015, jessica-jones

In S1E4, Audrey Eastman hires Jessica partially because she's gifted.

But since Jessica works pretty hard to minimize showing off her abilities, how did Audrey find out?

Is there a plausible explanation (e.g. a line of dialogue I missed) or is it just simply a plot hole?

Comment: I don't have the specific quote but Jessica says a couple times in the show she isn't hiding her powers, she just also isn't advertising them. There are several times in the show where she uses her powers in front of people and doesn't care if they tell others. Jeri knew about them, Jessica used her powers on the guy in the Aston Martin, broke the punching machine in front of a crowd, and she toppled all of the filing cabinets at her old job to intimidate her manager. She basically just doesn't care who knows

Answer (score 27, accepted):

She says later that she learned it from the wife of Gregory Spheeris, the guy Jessica served papers to, in an earlier episode, by lifting the back of his car:

> **Audrey:** She doesn't have laser eyes, either, or she would have used them.
>
> **Jessica:** Laser eyes? Who said I had laser eyes? Oh, that dick with the Aston Martin. I served him a subpoena.
>
> **Audrey:** Gregory Spheeris. I sell to his wife. They're very talky.
>
> <sup>*Marvel's Jessica Jones* Season 1 Episode 4: "99 Friends"</sup>

Comment: wow!  thanks for the fast reply and for clearing my head up.  :-)